# DanfoJS Apply-like operations with Dataframes

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pandas, dataframe

First of all, thank you for anyone willing to help me, and apologies for the simple question and if it's not written in the right place, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the answer.

The thing is, imagine the following Dataframe:

```
let data = [["R", 100], ["L", 200], ["R", "NULL"]]
let df = new dfd.DataFrame(data, {columns:["side", "value"]})

df.print()
```

[image]

What I want is to add a new column to that DF based on operations performed with one or several other columns, in a Pandas-like fashion. For example, imagine that I want to create a new column **result** that takes the following rule:

```
if (side === "R" && value !== "NULL" && value > 0) {
    result = value;
} else {
    result = 0;
}
```

The idea is to obtain the following DF:

[image]

In Pandas, this could be easily done by:

```
fn = lambda row: return row.value if row.side == "R" and row.value != "NULL" and row.value > 0 else 0
df["result"] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

However, as **Danfo does not support JS functions when specifying the axis** in `df.apply`, I find myself trying to implement weird workarounds that don't end anywhere

Is there a way in which I could implement this using Danfo? I have to perform several operations like this one to create several columns in my Dataframe, each column having its own rules and depending on other columns (can be one or more columns), and I wish to not have to traverse the whole df row by row with a classic for loop, ending up in not getting full advantage of Danfo